# How to launch PWA with a button?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA / website, which shows an **"Install"** Button, if the PWA is not installed

Once PWA is installed the **"Install"** button is hidden.

An option then appears in the address bar: **"To open this link, choose an app"**

[image]

How to code a button that launches the PWA if the users clicks on it in the browser mode?

Comment: Were you able to find out?

Comment: @gabriel290687 No, i was not able to. I gave up on the feature.